creating a bootable usb with GPT partition scheme to make use of linux .iso
The rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso to install from which is 14GB in size.
For a usb device (i.e. disk) that would show up in Linux as /dev/sdb for example, doing a cp rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sdb  results in an msdos partition scheme on that usb device which is bootable and allows you to install Linux.
I suspect they use the msdos partition scheme to maintain functionality with older hardware that pre-dates EFI
The msdos partition scheme has a 2TB limit, and poses an inconvenience when I have a 4+ TB usb disk that I want to use simultaneously for being able to install Linux from (which needs < 15GB of space on the device) and also make use of the remaining 4+ TB of the device and not be limited to a 2TB msdos partition.
So the solution seems to be to format the 4+ TB usb device with a GUID partition table i.e. GPT, where I can make one 4+ TB XFS partition on it but also convert or transfer the contents from the unpacked rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso to the GPT formatted device... and then marking that one (iso9660?) partition containing the Linux install content from the iso as bootable?
The contents of the unpacked rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso is
<folder>   [BOOT]
<folder>   AppStream
<folder>   BaseOS
<folder>   EFI
<folder>   images
<folder>   isolinux
           .discinfo
           .treeinfo
           EULA
           extra_files.json
           GPL
           media.repo
           RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta
           RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
           TRANS.TBL

is there a way for what I have described to manually do this Linux to make a usb device bootable (using parted or fdisk or some other) ?  If so how?  Or is there a way with some free software under microsoft windows?

Instead of trying to extract the ISO image’s contents and manually build a working USB key, I would use Ventoy. This allows you to create a generic  bootable key; then you add ISO images to it (as files stored on the key), and booting with the key gives you a menu to choose the image you actually want to boot from.
You can store any files you want alongside the boot images, or in directories.
Ventoy is available for Windows as well as Linux.
Note that some components of Ventoy are shipped as binary blobs in their source tree, which is causing concern in some circles; there’s an open issue asking for the blobs to be built from source during project builds. (This could be perfectly innocent, and a matter of convenience; but it leaves the project more vulnerable to xz-style attacks in the future.)
